# What options exist to prevent Google Chrome Frame from rendering external URLs?

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, security

What options exist to prevent Google Chrome Frame (GCF) from rendering external URLs?
I'd like to deploy GCF within our organization to allow some intranet sites to use modern html features. 
How can we ensure that all external internet sites continue to render with the host browser's engine?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you necessarily need to ensure that external sites are rendered with IE, as Google Chrome Frame is only "turned on" for websites which include the specific HTML meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1" />
```

Which means that it will only turn on for sites that have been developed to work with Chrome Frame. Forcing these sites to render in IE will only decrease performance.

Comment: Hi Matt, while I agree with you, there are some situations where an external site doesn't work at all when the tags are present. We're currently dealing with that now. Is there a way for Group Policy to override response headers?